# Markov Chains sufficient conditions and some definitions

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

So to prove something is Markov, we usually start from definitions, which is sometimes tricky, and quite inefficient at times. I am wondering is there any sufficient conditions we can easily (relatively ) to check that a sequence is Markov?

Also for communicating class, does a communicating class mean that if I am at one vertice, then I can travel to any other vertices in the class.

For a closed class, then that means there’s no output from the class?(so doesn’t act as a source)

Comment: What exactly do you mean that "a sequence is Markov"? That, e.g. a sequence of random variables $\{X_n, n\geqslant 0\}$ is a Markov chain under some set of transition probabilities?

Comment: @Math1000 yes that would be what I meant